# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client 2

Tags: express, middleware

Here is what my code first looked like:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const morgan = require('morgan')

app.use(morgan('tiny'));
// app.use((req, res, next) => {
//     console.log("OUR MIDDLEWARE")
//     console.log(req.method.toUpperCase(), req.path);
//     next();
// })

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.query);
    const { pwd } = req.query

    if (pwd === 'chickennugget') {
        next();
    }
    res.send("Sorry, you need a password")
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("HOME PAGE!!")
})

app.get('/dogs', (req, res) => {
    res.send("WOOF  WOOF!!")
})



app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("App is running on localhost:3000")
})
```

and it produced this error :

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/Users/tebahsaboun/Desktop/STUDIES/UDEMY/TWDB 2021/Section 40: Express/Middleware_Intro/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/tebahsaboun/Desktop/STUDIES/UDEMY/TWDB 2021/Section 40: Express/Middleware_Intro/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
    at /Users/tebahsaboun/Desktop/STUDIES/UDEMY/TWDB 2021/Section 40: Express/Middleware_Intro/app.js:19:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/tebahsaboun/Desktop/STUDIES/UDEMY/TWDB 2021/Section 40: Express/Middleware_Intro/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/tebahsaboun/Desktop/STUDIES/UDEMY/TWDB 2021/Section 40: Express/Middleware_Intro/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/tebahsaboun/Desktop/STUDIES/UDEMY/TWDB 2021/Section 40: Express/Middleware_Intro/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/tebahsaboun/Desktop/STUDIES/UDEMY/TWDB 2021/Section 40: Express/Middleware_Intro/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/tebahsaboun/Desktop/STUDIES/UDEMY/TWDB 2021/Section 40: Express/Middleware_Intro/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
```

and then I instinctively fixed it by modifying this particular piece of code:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.query);
    const { pwd } = req.query

    if (pwd === 'chickennugget') {
        return next();
    }
    res.send("Sorry, you need a password")
})
```

(I introduced a return before the next() function call.)

My question is two-fold:

- Why do I get this error with the initial code?
- Why introducing the "return"keyword. fixes the error?

I browsed StackOverFlow for an answer and there is an existing thread about this error but I don't see how the answer apply to my particular situation.

Thank you very much for your help.

Best,

Answer (score 0):

In the initial code the error is because, without the `return` statement, the server tries to send two responses. The first one was from the middleware:

```
res.send("Sorry, you need a password")
```

And the second one was the response from the actual routes.

The `return` fixes the error because when the variable pwd is equal to "chickennugget", the return statement stops the code there and never reads the:

```
res.send("Sorry, you need a password")
```

[You can read about the return statement here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return).

Comment: Thank you @monge1h